# ExternalInterface call from flash to function in OOP javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, callback, externalinterface

I can't call a javascript function from flash, when the flash object is added within an OOP structure in javascript. In short the code:

In flash:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {  
    ExternalInterface.call("flashMessages", "ready");
}
```

Code in javascript:

```
function fbTeaserClass(){

    function loadVideoObject(){
         ...
         swfobject.embedSWF(sitebase+'/FocusVideo.swf', 'myContent'+uniqueid, '100%', '100%', '9.0.0', 'expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes, outputStatus);
     }

    this.flashMessages=function(message){
        alert('called');
    }

}
```

Flash gets loaded, but the call to the javascript function isn't received. Anyone any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a scope issue, your function is inside an object, try calling "fbTeaserClass.flashMessage", you may need to initialise the flash at another level also.

Comment: You are right. A function called flashMessages(){..} is called (placed outside the object), only not in FireFox (other browsers give me the alert). Is that a common issue of FireFox?

Comment: If you change the code to do something other than an `alert()`, change something on the page for instance, does that work in FireFox?

Comment: FireFox does have a few issues with this, what do you have in your `attributes` variable?  If you could add in all the run up to the `SWFObject` call that would be handy.

Comment: In my attributes I have: var attributes = {
  id: 'flash'+uniqueid,
  name: 'flash'+uniqueid
 }

Comment: Also have some Params:  var params = {
  allowscriptaccess: 'always',
  wmode: 'transparent',
  allowFullScreen: 'true'
 };

Comment: It's solved: when I placed the swf-object in a javascript class for some reason a returning call from flash was send to soon for FireFox (worked fine in other browsers). I used a timeout on that function and now it functions fine! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bert: Glad it is fixed, timing on the Flash interface with regard to loading is always something to be aware of certainly.  I have heard that Flash is a bit flaky when the `name` and `id` field in attributes are set to the same thing.  Apparently removing `name` from that helps stabilise it in some flash client versions within FireFox.